# Error code C2451 cannot run basic program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a program which asks a question, and gives 1 of two answer based on the response (response = yes or no). Here is the code :-

```
 #include <iostream>

 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main()

{
    string answer, yes;

    cout << "Is Lucy a top lass ? enter yes or no" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == yes)

    {
        cout << "Correctomundo" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Blasphemy ! " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error C2451. Can anyone please explain how I must edit the code in order for it to work the way I want it to ?

I am using header files iostream, and string. this will not show for some reason as they are contained within triangular brackets.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (answer = yes)`

a) it's an assignment (`=`) not an equality check (`==`)

b) `yes` has no value - you probably meant something like `string answer, yes = "yes";` or just use `"yes"` directly instead of having a variable `yes`.

Comment: Could possibly provide a solution for b).

Comment: Thank you I have now got the program to run, however there is a runtime error. When I answer "yes" i get the output for the else statement "Blasphemy!" , i want it to output the if statement "Correctomundo". Is this because I need to assign a value to yes ? and if so how do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your line `if (answer = yes)` you are getting an error. I think what you meant to do was `if (answer == "yes")`. (Your `yes` string variable isn't initialized so I'm guessing you wanted it to be a string literal)

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional expression to

```
if(answer == yes)
```

You missed an = sign.
Doing this change will run your program without error. But variable yes has no value in it. So always the second the if condition will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You will get more information about **C2451** error [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb20073.aspx)

This error occurred at this line

```
if (answer = yes)
```

you are used an assignment operator rather than comparison operator
so when it compiles it become

```
if(answer)
```

and you are getting that error, change your code to

```
if (answer == yes)
```

So that it becomes the comparison operation. and also dont forgot to initialize the string variable *"yes"*
I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you I have edited the program, however I am now getting a runtime error , it gives the output for the else statement when I input yes. Do you know how to resolve this ?

Comment: because you didn't initialized yes variable.  string answer, yes = "yes"; or in if condition you have to check if(answer == "yes")